# Error in Visual Studio 2015 installation (install SDK 10 and Tools)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have VS2015 Community and I installed SDK 10 and Tools 1.4 for UWP apps several times, but I always get this message:

[image: Error Message]

I tried resetting the computer but nothing changes!

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want I can put LOG file.

Comment: Download the ISO, instead of download only the installer. : http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26892d8-6a5d-4871-9d46-629f4d430146/vs2015.3.vsu.iso

Comment: No , I downloaded the ISO and installed VS2015

Comment: After that I select SDK 10 and tools 1.4 for download , and that message was shown.

Comment: I think, you are the first, who got this error...:=) Bug report to Microsoft. Meanwhile, try to install the SDK standalone, download it here : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=698771

Comment: Bad luck! Yes I do that and after install it can't see UWP template! So I uninstall it and try to download by this way and for several times get that message!

Comment: VS2015 is very buggy. VS2015.2 if you open 2 instances at the same time, you environment settings will be mixed up and set to default settings.

Comment: Yes , you are right and I need it for training UWP apps and for a week I am trying to install it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Confim your Path is default.

   if the temp in your private path and vs may not work.
2. Keep your vs is the latest
3. Kill the other security soft.
4. Install your vs in C:\
5. Try install SDK 10240.

Answer (score 0):

try to create offline installer for VS not ISO & it will workout download size around 10 GB 
Run below command your updated(extract) VS2015 Update 3

vs_enterprise.exe or vs_community /layout D:\VisualStudio2015(Your local drive path)
More Info

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx

Comment: I don't think this way help to me.